# Java add ActionListener on a separate class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

Heres what I want to do, one of the classes is for a JFrame which contains all JButtons, I want another class to listen for the actions made on the JFrame class. 
See the code below:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{
    //all the jcomponents in here

}

public class listener implements ActionListener{
    //listen to the actions made by the Frame class

}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, you might want to choose different names for your classes. Java convention has classes starting with capital letters, however both `Frame` and `Listener` are classes in java already so you will have name conflicts if you are including that package. Something like Kumar's `MyListener` would work, or better yet name them based on what they do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a new instance of your listener to whatever components you want to listen. Any class that implements `ActionListener` can be added as a listener to your components.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    JButton testButton;

    public Frame() {
        testButton = new JButton();
        testButton.addActionListener(new listener());

        this.add(testButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the Listener class?

Comment: `testButton.addActionListener(new listener());` We are creating an instance of it right there.

Comment: @Ewen Listener is an interface not a class, when you do this.. button.addActionListener(new ActinoListener()); you are creating an anonymous class that Implements Interface ActinoListener ... SEE MY ANSWER

Comment: In his code sample he clearly has a class called `listener` that is implementing `ActionListener`. You don't have to use anonymous inner classes for everything and there is nothing wrong with having an external class implementing `ActionListener`. You can create an instance of it fine.

Comment: @JeffS, thats right.... its not necessary to create an Anonymous class, we can surely create another class which implements ActionListener, and pass its instance while registering it with the button. I was clearing Ewen's doubt on Anonymous class

Answer (score 3):

**1.** You can use `Inner Class`, or `Anonymous Inner Class` to solve this....

**Eg:**

**Inner Class**

```
public class Test{

 Button b = new Button();


 class MyListener implements ActionListener{

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    // Do whatever you want to do on the button click.
      } 

   }
}
```

**Eg:**

**Anonymous Inner Class**

```
public class Test{

     Button b = new Button();

     b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        // Do whatever you want to do on the button click.
          } 


   });

    }
```

Comment: Well actually thats a great idea but the purpose of doing listener on a different class is to not make the frame class too long and messy.

Comment: how to add action listener to class that extends button ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want one and the same instance of `listener` to listen to all of the buttons in the frame, you would have to make the actionPerformed method collect all clicks and delegate based on command:

```
public class listener extends ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("foo")) {
            handleFoo(e);
        } else if (command.equals("bar")) {
            handleBar(e);
        }
    }

    private void handleFoo(ActionEvent e) {...}
    private void handleBar(ActionEvent e) {...}
}
```

which will become easier in Java 7, where you can switch over strings!
The ActionCommand of a button click will be the `Text`-attribute of the `JButton`, unless you set it otherwise

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I've asked for.